# Passing data between apps in Python

Tags: python, flask, py-telegram-bot-api

I have a question about implementing passing data between two apps that I have running.

I have a Flask backend, which receives a user email via a POST request and stores it in a variable. I need to pass this variable into TelegramBotAPI.

What I need to happen is when Flask receives a new user email, it will pass the data into the TelegramBotAPI and trigger a function which will send it in a message to the user.

How do I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your architecture separates the TelegramBot from the Flask server, you would treat your flask server as the `client` for your Telegram Bot which is the `server` in this scenario.
Armed with this information there are numerous ways to go about this. TelegramBot could `provide an http server` through which clients could send requests. Another option which requires less availability from the Bot but ensures `eventual consistency` is using a `message broker` like RabbitMQ.
Lastly, if you wish to store the email permanently you should consider using a storage like a Database (for robustness) or a File system (if you have only one server)